# Show that a process $X(t)$ is Gaussian

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider a Process $X(t)$ were $t\in[0,1]$ where the process is defined to be the following...
\begin{equation}
X(t)=\alpha +B(t) -\beta t.
\end{equation}
Above I have taken the constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be real-valued and assumed $B(t)$ to be a standard Brownian motion.

How would one show that this is a Gaussian process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that the finite-dimensional distributions are gaussians: i.e. take $0\le t_1\le t_2\le\cdots\le t_n\le1$, consider the $n$-dimensional vector $(X(t_1),\cdots,X(t_n))$ and prove that it is a gaussian vector. But this is true, since it is an affine transformation of the vector $(B(t_1),\cdots,B(t_n))$ which is gaussian, since $B$ is Brownian Motion.

Comment: Is a linear transformation enough to give a firm answer?

Comment: Technically it is an affine transformation.

Comment: Yes Ian, you're right. Thanks.

By the way,whenever $X$ is a $n$-dim gaussian vector, then $AX+b$ is such for every $A\in\mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$ and $b\in\Bbb R^m$.